# How is designing shape similar to waves with html and css?

Tags: html, css, svg

i need to help for design a shape for footer in project similar to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTE9I.jpg). please help me.
How is designing shape similar to waves with html and css. with border-radius is possible or with SVG?

Is it possible to be responsive?

my svg code:

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="100%" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 1366 432"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<g transform="translate(0.000000,432.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M0 1710 l0 -1710 10000 0 10000 0 0 114 0 113 -127 100 c-833 653
-1848 1155 -2883 1427 -681 179 -1808 322 -3055 388 -328 18 -1972 18 -2340 0
-1091 -51 -1781 -111 -3645 -317 -1898 -209 -2407 -249 -3230 -249 -682 -1
-1004 26 -1490 125 -1101 225 -2207 812 -2996 1590 l-131 129 -51 0 -52 0 0
-1710z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

**but it not fullwith.**  [try it](https://jsfiddle.net/xq65n44m/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your SVG file.  Change:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
```

to

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely tricky to pull that off with pure css. I would try using a CSS shape builder tool online if you truly want to use CSS.

Make this will help? http://html-generator.weebly.com/css-shape-generator.html#y